# Remove menu item name/alias from url in joomla

Tags: url-rewriting, url-routing, joomla2.5, joomla-sef-urls, sef

I have a menu and when i click a menu item i am redirected to the items content.

So i am in the **domain.com/menuitem** page. 
In the current page i have some categories and when i click on a category i get redirected to its content.

So i am in the **domain.com/menuitem/category** page. When i am on that page i dont want the menu item name to be shown. I want **domain.com/category**

How could i achieve that by NOT using any external sef component?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new level 1 menu item, of the "Category page" type, and give it the alias "category".

Comment: Is if possible to achieve this without creating menu item.